# After getting Cell Info, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I'm using CellStumbler to obtain the iPhone's cell ID, location area code and other information.

After calling getInfo, I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I can't figure out why. This is all undocumented private functions, but certainly someone can help. The problem isn't associated with any of the lines in the function, it's only after running it that it happens.

[Cell Stumbler](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/source/browse/trunk/CellStumbler/main.c?r=140)

I'm aware this isn't App Store approvable.

```
  int cellcount;
_CTServerConnectionCellMonitorGetCellCount(&t1,sc,&cellcount);

printf("Cell count: %x\n",cellcount);

printf("Size = %lx\n", sizeof(struct CellInfo));

unsigned char *a=malloc(sizeof(struct CellInfo));

for(b=0;b<cellcount;b++)
{       
    _CTServerConnectionCellMonitorGetCellInfo(&t1,sc,b,a); memcpy(&cellinfo,a,sizeof(struct CellInfo));
    printf("Cell Site: %d, MNC: %d, ",b,cellinfo.servingmnc);
    printf("Location: %d, Cell ID: %d, Station: %d, ",cellinfo.location, cellinfo.cellid, cellinfo.station);
    printf("Freq: %d, RxLevel: %d, ", cellinfo.freq, cellinfo.rxlevel);
    printf("C1: %d, C2: %d\n", cellinfo.c1, cellinfo.c2);
}
if(a) free(a);
```

This is the getCellInfo function available in the CellStumbler project above. The error occurs after this is called, but not necessarily in this function, only after, as if an after effect of running this is some memory mangling.

Comment: Please include some of your code. Perhaps even the part that is causing the error?

Comment: Added the function that after being called crashes the app. It's not in any line within the function, only after its run.

Comment: hey can you help me out. It is still crashing for me. I have posted the question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425211/how-to-fix-ctserverconnectionregisterfornotification-crash-happening-in-vafield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've temporarily solved this problem, by removing the for loop and only running _CTServerConnectionCellMonitorGetCellInfo once.