# Get Cell-Tower information on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, core-telephony

I am working on a field-testing application which targets on iPhone 4. Therefore, it would be kind of cool, to get any information on the Serving Cell.
I can get the signal strength using CoreTelephony:

```
int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(ptrLibraryHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
sstrngth = CTGetSignalStrength();
```

That works pretty good on iOS 4.3 and even 5.0. But does anyone of you know how to access CellInfo from out the same (or maybe a different?) library?

I tried it with an UI application and with an iOS commandline application (working through openssh on the phone) - without success: The returned number of cells is always 0 whereas, however, the connection to the cell service did succeed.

Used this code: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/source/browse/trunk/CellStumbler/main.c?r=140

From that post: [After getting Cell Info, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532677/after-getting-cell-info-exc-bad-access-is-thrown/9941068#9941068)

(I answered on that post with a question, and I don't know yet how community handles answers which are actually questions, so I created a real question)

Does anybody has got this code (or other code accomplishing the same) running?

Comment: Isn't that a private API? You're not hoping to release this if it is, are you?

Comment: yes, this is absolutely private. I am aware, that apple will reject apps which link against private apis.