# How to fix _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification crash happening in VAFieldTest application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, core-telephony

I am trying to run `VAFieldTest` application in my device, but the application got crashed at this line `_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification`. How can I fix this crash?

Here are the parameters I have passed:

```
CTServerConnectionRef conn;
void register_notification(){
    if (!mach_port || !conn) return;    
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    void *kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification = dlsym(libHandle, "kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification");
    if( kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification== NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification"); 
    int x = 0; //placehoder for callback
    _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(conn,kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification,(void*)&x);
}
```

[image]

Here is the crash report:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x344f9710 in __CFStrConvertBytesToUnicode ()
#1  0x344faaea in __CFStringEncodeByteStream ()
#2  0x34466a10 in CFStringGetBytes ()
#3  0x39123928 in ctu::cf::assign ()
#4  0x39112380 in getCTEventForNotification ()
#5  0x390ecff8 in _CTServerConnectionDaemonRegistration ()
#6  0x39112e12 in _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification ()
#7  0x00003138 in register_notification () at /Users/deepthi/Desktop/iPhone Agent/VAFieldTest-master/Classes/VAFieldTestViewController.m:66
#8  0x00003388 in -[VAFieldTestViewController viewDidLoad] (self=0x15ada0, _cmd=0x34b8581b) at /Users/deepthi/Desktop/iPhone Agent/VAFieldTest-master/Classes/VAFieldTestViewController.m:116
#9  0x3471458c in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#10 0x00002d84 in -[VAFieldTestAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (self=0x11f350, _cmd=0x34b698d3, application=0x11e510, launchOptions=0x0) at /Users/deepthi/Desktop/iPhone Agent/VAFieldTest-master/Classes/VAFieldTestAppDelegate.m:22
#11 0x34755ad0 in -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] ()
#12 0x3475565a in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
#13 0x3474d842 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#14 0x346f5c38 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#15 0x346f56cc in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#16 0x346f511a in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#17 0x394785a2 in _PurpleEventCallback ()
#18 0x344e9682 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#19 0x344e8ee8 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#20 0x344e7cb6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#21 0x3445aebc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#22 0x3445ad48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#23 0x3474c47c in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#24 0x347492f8 in UIApplicationMain ()
#25 0x00002cf6 in main (argc=1, argv=0x2fdffc50) at /Users/deepthi/Desktop/iPhone Agent/VAFieldTest-master/main.m:15
(gdb)
```

Comment: Edit your question with error log.

Comment: @iHungry I have enabled Zombies, even though nothing got printed in console. It says EXC_BAD_ACCESS at _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification line. I have attached the screenshot above. Can you please check that.

Comment: @iAmbitious Updated my question with error log. Can you verify it now.

Comment: @Dee did you find any way out here?

Answer (score 0):

When I got this, it was caused by the 3rd argument in the call to _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(...) which should be a pointer to a callback...described here - [incompactable pointer type passing int to parameter of type void(*)(void) in coretelephony obj c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275026/incompactable-pointer-type-passing-int-to-parameter-of-type-voidvoid-in-cor)