# incompactable pointer type passing int to parameter of type void(*)(void) in coretelephony obj c

Tags: c++, c, core-telephony

The function defined in coreTelephony.h is

```
void _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(CTServerConnectionRef,void *,void(*callback)(void));
```

Then I tried to call this function

```
int x = 0; //placehoder for callback
_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(conn,kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification,&x);
```

it return the error

> incompatible pointer type passing int to parameter of type void(*)(void) in coretelephony obj c

What am I missing?

Comment: why did you revert the earlier edit?

Comment: Where did you find that declaration? It's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here, the third argument to `_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification()` is meant to be a pointer to a function having

- `void` return type
- Accepting no parameter.

You cannot pass the address of an `int` in that case. It is wrong and will cause [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the reply...then how can i pass int varible?

Comment: @sai it's called `reply`, not `replay`. :-) and why'd you pass a pointer to `int` there in first place?

Comment: :) i just tried  _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(conn,kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification,x);   but it return same warning

Comment: This is my code

void register_notification(){
    if (!mach_port || !conn) return;
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    void *kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification = dlsym(libHandle, "kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification");
    if( kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification== NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification");
    int x = 0; //placehoder for callback
    _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(conn,kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification,&x);
    
}

the last line return error

Comment: @sai you're not getting the point. why you're passing something which is __not a function pointer__?

Comment: i didnt get u...i dont know more about c

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of `_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification` is a function pointer, and you pass a pointer to an `int`. Even if you succeeded to do it using casts, later when the connection needs to notify you it will try to use the value you passed as a function, and since it is not a function, you most likely will see a crash.

Use a function not an int:

```
void callback()
{
}
```

and then in your current code:

```
_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(conn,kCTCellMonitorUpdateNotification,&callback);
```